# a single eclipse plugin for counting the logical lines of code in a J2EE project

Tags: eclipse, plugins, lines-of-code

Is there a way to get the count of logical lines of code in .java, .js, .jsp, .xml files?
I have tried Metrics. It only counts the logical lines of code in .java files.